# aiohttp: how to make simple http request

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am exploring aiohttp for async http requests.

The client quickstart on the aiohttp [website](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request)   suggests this code as a minimal example:

```
import aiohttp
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
        print(resp.status)
        print(await resp.text())
```

For me on python 3.6.5 this results in

> async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Am I missing something here?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

#### edit:

I was doing test. First I realized I needed python 3.7.
So I switched and now the error message is:

> async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
>
> SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not due to Python version: aiohttp supports Python >= 3.5.3, so 3.6.5 is absolutely fine. But note the error message:

> SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function

That's it: you can use `async with` only inside an async function:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def start():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            print(await resp.text())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start())
```

The message is true for Python 3.5 and 3.6 also, they've only made it more friendly in 3.7

Comment: @caliph btw some short fully runnable examples can be found at index page of the site https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/index.html